# IOS swift avplayer inside UiView how can I make it work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview, avplayer

I am new to using the AVPlayer for IOS swift and got it working correctly. However I would like the video to play inside a UIView right now the video takes up the whole page as default . I have been trying a few things and nothing works here is my code . I have other content on that page that is why I would like the avplayer inside the UIVIEW which is called **newView** and when I put the code below it gives me an error. I have been following this example [AVPlayerLayer Position in UIView Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259604/avplayerlayer-position-in-uiview-layer)

```
    import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import WebKit
import AVKit

class ExampleTable: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!

    let avPlayerViewController = CustomAVPLayerC()
    var playerView: AVPlayer?
    var AVLayer: AVPlayerLayer?


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let movieURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "my url")

        playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieURL! as URL)
        avPlayerViewController.player = playerView
        playerView?.isMuted = true
  avPlayerViewController.view.frame = newView.frame
   newView.addSubview(avPlayerViewController.view)
   addChildViewController(avPlayerViewController)
        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) {
            self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


}
```

However when I do the code above I get this error

```
2017-08-16 15:55:31.770 Yisly[24335:595275] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <app.ExampleTable: 0x7ff78201a650>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aab9b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109dec141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010b910e44 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 5146
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010c28e165 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 294
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010c28a0e4 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _runAlongsideCompletions] + 155
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010c289dbc -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 118
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b8d3b70 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 251
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b8d37e8 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1408
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b8d5eb8 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b7e6f07 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 222
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b7e7446 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 136
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b5ca68e _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 306
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010da4f05c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010da3040b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 411
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa7e909 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa44ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2164
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa44016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f203a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010b75b0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    19  Yisly                               0x0000000105c10117 main + 55
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010da9b65d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: remove self.present(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) {...}?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting the error message because you are trying to present the same instance of your `CustomAVPlayerC` that you just added as a child view controller. You don't need to present the VC, try this code which is a little cleaner approach:

```
@IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!
let avPlayerViewController = CustomAVPlayerC()
var playerView: AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let movieURL = URL(string: "my url")
        else { return }

    playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)
    avPlayerViewController.player = playerView
    avPlayerViewController.view.frame = newView.bounds
    self.addChildViewController(avPlayerViewController)
    newView.addSubview(avPlayerViewController.view)
    avPlayerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

I would recommend going over Apple's documentation on ["Implementing a Container View Controller"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) for best practices in dealing with a container view set up like this.